# Laravel - PDO - Dynamic Table Names

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I am trying to delete a table with a dynamic name. I actually generate and manipulate tables dynamically, but this is the simplest of the queries.

Everything works fine when I use raw PDO, like so:

```
// PURE PDO VERSION
$this->db = new PDO(
    'mysql:host='   . $configParams['db_hostname']
    . ';port='      . $configParams['db_port']
    . ';dbname='    . $configParams['db_name']
    . ';charset=utf8mb4',
    $configParams['db_username'],
    $configParams['db_password']
);

$this->ps_DeleteTempTable = $db->prepare(
            "DROP TABLE `:tableName`"
        );
```

But when I do the same using Laravel, like so:

```
// LARAVEL VERSION
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();

$this->ps_DeleteTempTable = $pdo->prepare(
            "DROP TABLE `:tableName`"
        );
```

I receive the following error :

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testdb.?'
>   doesn't exist

I have seen other questions on SO with similar aims, but they all suggest the first query I wrote cannot be work, whereas I have been using it for over a year.

Thanks,

Comment: If you actually had it working, I can't explain that - because placeholders should only work for values, not column or table names

Comment: I got it working using backticks, I create/insert/update/delete without problems. It's just odd that when going through laravel it stops working.

Comment: This is quite mysterious if you actually had it working... Because when preparing, singlequotes are automatically added around values - do you *should*  get query looking like `DROP TABLE \`testdb.'table'\`` - which is invalid. What version of PHP and MySQL you got running? Can you show how you execute the binds too?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the table name as a value when building the SQL...

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();

$this->ps_DeleteTempTable = $pdo->prepare(
            "DROP TABLE `".$tableName."`"
        );
```

You could get some odd results when not using back ticks as the names may be reserved words. In general it's better to design the database not to use these, but some are quite common ('order' for example)